# How to update specific repo in yum?

Tags: rpm, yum

I have multiple repos like RepoA.repo, RepoB.repo, RepoC.repo. I want to update only RepoA.repo as new RPMs will get add into it daily.
How can I update only RepoA.repo rather than using "yum update" which updates all the repos and takes long time.

Thanks,
MadEngineer

Answer (score 8):

There is no problem; because if no new rpms will be added to repoB and repoC; then the update will only take new rpms from repoA. If you really want to make sure that all your updates come from repoA; and none from another repository; you can just update while disabling all repositories *execpt* repoA:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="repoA" update
```

Reference: [here](http://mcvictech.blogspot.be/2012/06/yum-update-from-specific-repository.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you meant you wanted to clear the metadata for only a single repo because you know it is stale, you can do:

```
yum clean all --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=<repo>
```